# MySQL : strange LENGTH() behaviour on utf8 string

Tags: mysql, encoding, string-length

I am doing unit tests on requests generators, and I get in trouble with `LENGTH` function.

I have 2 requests that follows each other :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%'
```

Returns the following result :

```
array(8) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(20) "character_set_client"
    'Value' =>
    string(4) "utf8"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(24) "character_set_connection"
    'Value' =>
    string(4) "utf8"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(22) "character_set_database"
    'Value' =>
    string(6) "latin1"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(24) "character_set_filesystem"
    'Value' =>
    string(6) "binary"
  }
  [4] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(21) "character_set_results"
    'Value' =>
    string(4) "utf8"
  }
  [5] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(20) "character_set_server"
    'Value' =>
    string(4) "utf8"
  }
  [6] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(20) "character_set_system"
    'Value' =>
    string(4) "utf8"
  }
  [7] =>
  array(2) {
    'Variable_name' =>
    string(18) "character_sets_dir"
    'Value' =>
    string(26) "/usr/share/mysql/charsets/"
  }
}
```

My second request is :

```
SELECT LENGTH('重庆') as len
```

It returns 6 instead of 2.

What's wrong here ? My charset parameters looks good.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found my answer in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) :

The `LENGTH` function counts **bytes** :

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH('重庆') ;
+------------------+
| LENGTH('重庆')   |
+------------------+
|                6 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `CHAR_LENGTH` function counts **characters** :

```
mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('重庆') ;
+-----------------------+
| CHAR_LENGTH('重庆')   |
+-----------------------+
|                     2 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: More specifically, `LENGTH()` returns the length of its argument in *bytes* whereas `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of its argument in *characters*.

Comment: More specifically, `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of its argument in *code points*.
`SELECT LENGTH('‍‍‍'), CHAR_LENGTH('‍‍‍') ` returns `25`, `7`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27331885

Answer (score 3):

They both work completely different:

Once LENGTH() returns always the length of the string by bytes. CHAR_LENGTH() is gonna return the length of the string by characters.

Once you are using Unicode, in which most characters are encoded in two bytes, It is always gonna be different. Or even when we are talking about UTF-8, where the number of bytes varies all the time.

e.g.:

```
SELECT LENGTH('重庆'), CHAR_LENGTH('重庆');
-->   6,  2
```

Comment: your comment is wrong, Unicode does not encode in two bytes, because it is simply not an encoding. Maybe you are talking about UTF-16. Unicode is only a specification about code points.